C# routine to create derived classes from an abstract class
I am trying to develop a routine that will run an sql statement and use the results to populate class objects that are derived from an abstract class, something like the following:
public static List<T> PopulateList<T>(string sql)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    // get sql data
    foreach (row in resultset)
    {
        list.Add(new T(row));
    }
    return list;
}

The constructor of the abstract class (i.e., "T") calls an abstract/virtual method which, of course, would be overidden and potentially different for each derived class.
The problem is that C# won't allow an abstract class object to be created and populated even though it represents and will be used for a derived class object.
How can I accomplish this?
I have tried to design the routine but haven't figured out a way to get it to work.

new T is invalid if T is abstract. You must new a concrete class.

Do you imagine that each row might lead to a different derivation of T, i.e. a different concrete type? Would that be useful? Of course, the most common thing to do is to write the classes that inherit T before the program runs, not to somehow emit new types while the program is running.

The derived classes would be written in the app to inherit the T abstract class.  This would NOT be used to emit new types.

"Do you imagine that each row might lead to a different derivation of T, i.e. a different concrete type?"  Yes - exactly - that is the point.  The user would create as many versions of derived classes as they need to represent different sql queries

Could you have static method static T Construct(Row row) { ... } where T is your abstract class (not a generic type)? Then have logic in the method that, depending on values inside row, return a new A or B or C etc.?

There is no magic solution to this. You have to use conditional code. Somewhere, you need to use an if or a switch to decide what type to create based on some condition. The WebRequest.Create method is one that will return an instance of a derived type based on the URI you pass in but, internally, it basically does what I said above. There is no avoiding it. You can't just magic objects of arbitrary types out of nothing.

It's a code smell to call a virtual method in the constructor, and for good reason. But for your code specifically, if T is the abstract class, how are you going to define which of the actual methods is supposed to be called if you don't specify the derived class?


The problem is that C# won't allow an abstract class object to be created and populated even though it represents and will be used for a derived class object.

Yes indeed. So you have MyAbstractClass with some abstract methods. You can implement a class that extends your MyAbstractClass and implements the abstract methods in some dummy manner and use this MyDerivedClass instead.
